# How to import native iOS framework in Kony IDE

Tags: ios, temenos-quantum

Im trying to integrate an iOS framework in Kony. I've tried to follow the documentation to import a native framework using the `Manage Native Function API(s)` menu, however I get the following error: "Error while importing framework .zip extract error: undefined".
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't imported for iOS. But below are the steps to import or add a native framework to the project.

We are using Kony Visualizer Enterprise 7.3. Please find the steps below.

Goto Edit -> Manage Native Function

[image: Goto Edit -> Manage Native Function]

Select Import option under IOS tab
[image: Select Import option under IOS tab]

Select the valid .zip IOS framework file which you need to import.
If you are getting error, please double check if the file is the right/valid one. Try to import any other framework zip to verify if it is working.

Alternative if you want to use existing one, please select Add
[image: Alternative if you want to use existing one, please select Add]

Hope this helps. Thanks.